# vscode live server not auto reload if config proxy is config

Tags: visual-studio-code, proxy, reload

If I config liveServer.settings.proxy, browser not auto reload if html or css file change.

But if I disable liveServer.settings.proxy, all is fine, browser auto reload if any change on my html css files.

I need to use proxy. any solution? or other extension can help me? thanks